# How can i show post of specific terms and post types?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display post of specific terms ids and post types. I am trying following arguments of wordpress query but it does not work.

```
$PRODUCT_LIST_ARGS = array(
    'post_type' => array('float_post_type','spark_post_type'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'float',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array(5),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'spark',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array(13),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what is it giving?

Comment: @flauntster it does not showing any result or post

Comment: Ok so you're getting nothing, what if you remove the tax query do you get all of the post types?